# How to fast forward a branch to another non-master branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I am on branch B.
When checking out branch A, I get the message that I am behind branch A by one commit.

`git checkout A
Switched to branch 'A'
Your branch is behind 'origin/A' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.`

But when on my own branch, I cannot do git pull A because it says that A does not appear to be a repository.

I am also confused because when I do `git merge A`, the message is that this is already up to date. How can this be when I'm behind by one commit?

What can I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

git pull is simply a fetch+merge, however it only updates the branch you're working on when it pulls. The references of all branches are updated, so git is aware that local A ref is outdated.

```
# on branch A
git merge origin/A --ff-only
```

This will update your history with the latest status of A.

Comment: For some reason it says it's already up to date, but I'm behind one commit?

Comment: Please paste the message that says you're behind.

Answer (score 0):

> Your branch is behind 'origin/A' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded

Pull `origin/A` branch into local branch `A`

```
$ git checkout A
$ git pull origin A
```

Comment: If he is behind _A_ by one commit, then why would he want to pull `master`?